# Use of const with typedef-ed type

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constants, c++11

The following code compiles fine on majority of compilers (include Microsoft Visual Studio's - cl, Minimalist GNU for Windows - MinGW) but fails on **Digital Mars Compiler - dmc** with the error: `Error: type qualifiers and static can only appear in outermost array of function parameter`

```
const int MAXLENGTH32 = 32;
typedef char String32[MAXLENGTH32];

void f1(const String32 tokens[]) {

}

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to state the following:

1. The first reason I am posting this is to get expert opinion on why the code fails on a popular compiler (Bjarne Stroustrup himself recommends it http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/compilers.html). The main problem seems to be the use of `const` with the parameter. If you remove `const`, the code compiles fine on the **DMC** compiler.
2. The second important reason is that in my investigation on the possible explanation for compilation failure, I did not come across any conclusive explanation. Worse, I came across the suggestion: "C++ programmers to just avoid using const". The poster went on to say that its rather difficult to figure out just what the specifications says about the usage of `const` in a scenario like above and that these kinds of things are why const, as a type modifier, is not in D (- to paraphrase sort of).
3. The last personal reason for this post is that most exceptional things I have learnt about C++ language have been borne out of not taking a stance like it-compiles-on-all-the-rest-so-damn-it-and-move-on. Yes. Am eager to hear expert opinion on what could make what would seem like normal code fail on **DMC** compiler just like that. Thanks.

Comment: Popular compiler? I've never seen DMC used outside of D context.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I usually compile C++ code with 3 compilers. MinGW, DMC, and Microsoft's own CL that comes with VS. I might have wrongly taken any of them too seriously that it ought to. Which top 3 (that dont come with everything but the kitchen-sink) would you recommend? ;) I know this is a different question altogether

Comment: GCC, Clang and MSVC. Though if you're serious about C++11 support, then drop MSVC.

Comment: @Cat: If you're serious about C++11 *language* support. The library support is fully there. And even the most general-use useful C++11 language stuff is there (`auto`, lambdas, move semantics). You're missing variadic templates and template aliases, but I don't think those are needed in general. The one MSVC implements are much much more useful.

Comment: @Xeo: Language support is far more important than library support. Library can be pulled from Boost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious explination is that there is a bug in dmc.  The error 
message is excedingly confusing: for starters, `static` cannot appear
anywhere in a function parameter, outermost or otherwise.  As for type
qualifiers, the standard is clear that type qualifiers on an array apply
to the individual elements of the array (and that this applies
recursively).  Written canonically, your function declaration would be:

```
void f1(String32 const* tokens)
```

, which, after application of the typedef, becomes:

```
void f1( char const (*tokens)[MAXLLENGTH32] );
```

Which is perfectly legal.

Comment: +1 for this *" As for type qualifiers, the standard is clear that type qualifiers on an array apply to the individual elements of the array (and that this applies recursively)"*

Comment: @JamesKanze ... it does seem to make sense if you think about it being equivalent to `void f1(char const (*tokens)[MAXLENGTH32])`. My main reason for hesitation to acknowledge it as a possible bug is owing to the fact that some of the earliest reports related to this that I came across on the Web are dated year 2003. I thought that was a long time for a "bug" to remain unfixed - other than for it being extremely difficult to fix. Meanwhile, it does sound like where I need to start reading up is on application of type qualifiers to arrays. Thanks

Comment: @JohnGathogo All compilers have bugs.  And some take longer to get fixed than others.